# Configure systemd journald to both forward and store in persistent journal?

Tags: systemd-journald

With systemd some things changed. So instead of tailing a specific file, I could now use `journalctl` to access the journal.

However, in [`/etc/systemd/journald.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/journald.conf.5.html) under `[Journal]` the option `Storage=persistent` seems to conflict with `ForwardToSyslog=yes`.

My intention here would be to enable the use of `journalctl` for the more recent events, say within a predefined period of a few days (e.g. `MaxRetentionSec=1month`) but **also** forward all events to my syslogd instance.

However, using `journalctl -xe` I can see that those messages that made it to syslogd definitely didn't make it to the persistent systemd journal.

How can I enable such a mode, i.e. to log into the persistent system journal **and** forward to syslogd?

```
# systemd --version
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about your conclusion. Though I only have version 219, I see the same lines appearing in my `/var/log/messages` through syslog, as in the output of `sudo journalctl --follow`, for example when I do an ssh or `logger -p kern.err abc` or stop a service with systemctl.

I am using the default `journald.conf` of `Storage=auto` (which is similar to persistent when you have a directory `/var/log/journal`) and `ForwardToSyslog=yes`, with `rsyslogd`.

Note, you need to `sudo journalctl` to be able to read all the logs.

Comment: You do not actually need to `sudo`.  You need to be a member of the `systemd-journal` group.